# Things listener does not get triggered when Thing is updated by Hub-Things Connection

Tags: bosch-iot-suite

I've a strange problem.

1. I have created a Thing.
2. My Thing's Policy has BOTH entries for Authorization for my Hub-Things Connection as well as for my Java Client (Things Client ID).
3. I can verify that the Hub-Things Connection DOES update my thing since values change.

Whenever the Hub-Things connection updates my Thing, my Java Things listener is not called/updated. However, whenever my Thing is manually updated via Things REST call (e.g. PUT ​/things​/{thingId}​/features), my Things Listener gets called.

Any clues?

I'm using the Bosch IoT Cloud Instance of IoT Things.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. Maybe there is a problem with the registration itself but the connection receives the events nonetheless. To check this, could you please set the log level of `com.bosch.iot.things.client.messaging.internal.thingsws.ThingsWsMessagingProvider` to `DEBUG` and check if it receives the events?

Comment: Ok it looks like it happens in version 3.2.x of the Things Client. Updating this to v4.0.0 of the Library seems to have fixed it.